# JMRTD Doing Chip Authentication returns Invalid Data Objects

Tags: java, android, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Using the below code with **JMRTD** [JMTD Library](https://jmrtd.org/), I am trying to read the card contactless with an Android device. I am getting the following error while doing **CHIP AUTHENTICATION** which I can not determine the reason for this, **PACE** and reading data groups was successfully done before this step.

```
service = new PassportService(cs, maxTranceiveLength, PassportService.DEFAULT_MAX_BLOCKSIZE, false, true);

caResult = service.doEACCA(caPubKeyInfo.getKeyId(), caProtoInfo.getObjectIdentifier(), caPubKeyInfo.getSubjectPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), caPubKeyInfo.getSubjectPublicKey());
```

net.sf.scuba.smartcards.CardServiceException: Exception during transmission of wrapped APDU,  (SW = 0x6988: SM DATA OBJECTS INCORRECT)

What could be the reason for this error?